# How to print all the cells inside a square when given the two opposite coordinates

Tags: c++, matrix, square

I have a 10x10 matrix. I have to form a square and find all the cells inside it when given the opposite coordinates of the square.
Example
given 1B,3D as the coordinates to form a square. 
I need to print 1B,1C, 1D, 2B, 2C, 2D, 3B, 3C, 3D

Since the values are string how do I get started with this

Comment: convert first character to integer (atoi()), find difference between first ccoordinate for both points  - it will be length of square side. construct two other point adding this lenght

Comment: `for (auto i = '1'; i <= '3'; ++i) for (auto j = 'B'; j <= 'D'; ++j) std::cout << i << j << ' ';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most systems work with ASCII. ASCII has the property that 'A'+1 == 'B', 'B'+1 == 'C' and so on. Also C++ guarantees that '0'+1 == '1', '1'+1 == '2' and so on. Therefor you can simply

```
void f(const std::string &lhs, const std::string &rhs) {
    bool first = true;
    for(char i = lhs[0]; i <= rhs[0]; ++i) {
        for(char j = lhs[1] ; j <= rhs[1]; ++j) {
            std::cout << (first ? "" : ", ") << i << j;
            first = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
void printSquare(string a, string b){

    int start = stoi(a.substr (0, a.length()-1));   
    int end =  stoi(b.substr (0, b.length()-1));   
    char s = a[a.length()-1];
    for(int i=0;i<=end-start;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<=end-start;j++){
            cout<<1+i << char(s+j);
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }

}
```

Convert cells to an integer using `atoi` and `substr` methods. Assuming only the last character can be a string. Otherwise, we need to iterate over each character and check whether the char is between 0-9 or not.

Once we have corners of the square iterate over the length and print that simply.

https://ideone.com/6OFHM1